# Update XML values using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a number of XML documents (c. 100,000 lines each) which I need to update the values of using an CSV document which has the correct values in.

The data relates to buildings and each building has a reference number stored like this

```
<Property Version="1" ID="PY303466" IDType="Test" Reference="12345" Name="Test1; July 2018">
```

And then the building data is stored within the children / sub-children of this tag. My thinking is that I can somehow extrapolate the reference number, then iterate through the various tags and then replace the values in the XML document with the values in the CSV.

I'm relatively new to Python, and very new to XML - with the exception of a bit of web-scraping.

I am wondering if my use case is viable, and if anyone has any experience doing something like this is there any guidance / tips you could give me? I have struggled to find resources for this type of task online.

Comment: you should first read your xml with python xml minidom, replace the values in minidom object, convert your minidom object to xml file. Various properties of minidom could be used to replace the value

Comment: This sounds like a perfectly normal task, but the question is a bit vague and it's hard to provide concrete advice. Have you written any code that parses an XML document and extracts information from it? Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance @mzjn, I have followed the docs and can pull out bits of the data I want. But didn't seem to be moving closer to getting what I want to do. I suspect there is a little bit of misunderstanding of XML on my part here, so will keeep going through the docs!

Comment: I think you should try to narrow the question down to a specific, reproducible problem. Otherwise there is a risk that the question gets closed for being unclear or too broad.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks yes I agree, I will delete it myself and come back once I have a better understanding of the proccess myself.

Comment: @Maverick If you provide example of your XML file, CSV file, expected output and code that you've made so far we can help you faster.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks I will do that! I just need to anonymise the data.